# Audit deleted file by Linux client from Windows Server

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I using a Windows Server 2012 for network file sharing (domain) and turn on audit policy for event file delete.

When a client using Windows OS access network share folder then delete some file, the audit logs information correctly (who, when deleting), but if a client using Linux OS delete files, the server cannot log who delete (Security ID, Account Name) as images below.

Audit info when a Windows client deletes file:
[image]

Audit info when a Linux client deletes file:
[image]

So there is the limit of Windows server?

Comment: The second file is not deleted by a user object, it's deleted by a computer (SYSTEM). That would be the same if done from windows. Just deny access to the ressource for computers/system.

Comment: When a Linux client access network share on Windows server via SMB, it needs authentication by user account (the domain account). Windows server can log who delete file if the action from Windows client but not Linux (just log like the second image).